# Use a variable both as function and object instance

Tags: javascript, object

I was wondering how does JQuery use "$" both as a function to return a new instance and an instance itself.
I guess that it's not exactly the case but I mean, we can use `$(element).method` and for exemple `$.ajax` without brackets (.ajax will still be a method).

**EDIT :** 
I think that I misspoke. I know how objects work in JavaScript and my question was not about that.
JQuery allows us to use `$` without the key word `new`. It has a function that returns a new instance automatically. So my question was about how it can use `$` both as a function to instanciate a new object and an object itself.
Let's say we have

```
(function() {

var jQ = function (arg){

    this.own = arg;

};

jQ.prototype = {

    foo : function (){

        alert("Foo");

    },

    bar : function (){

        alert("Bar");

    }

};

window.jQ = window.$ = jQ;

return jQ;
```

}());
In this exemple, i have to go througth the key word `new` if I want to use my object.
So how does JQuery do to avoid us this step ?

Comment: Do you know what `prototype` means in JavaScript?

Comment: Functions are objects and can be used as such.

Answer (score 2):

Function is an object in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function You can check this code:

```
var f = function () { alert(1); };
f.func1 = function () { alert(2); };
f.func2 = function () { alert(3); };
```

and you can call `f()`, `f.func1()` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

It's not jQuery. In JavaScript functions are objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `$(element).method` you are passing a parameter `element` into the jQuery function, where with the `$.ajax`call you are calling the ajax function inside of the `$` jQuery object.  In both cases we are talking about the same piece of code, but we are using it two different ways.

Have a look at the raw source code for jQuery and that should help to visualize this a little: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js
Note: the jQuery function that is used repeatedly is aliased at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in JavaScript, functions are objects. So, using the specific functions you called out in your question, you could create them like this:

```
var $ = function(selector) {
    ...
};

$.ajax = function(url) {
    ...
};
```

EDIT: To respond to your edited/clarified question, you don't have to use prototyping to make constructor functions in javascript. Remember, all a constructor is doing is returning an object - here's the equivalent of your prototyping code, but without having to use the new operator to instantiate the object:

```
(function() {

var jQ = function (arg){

    return {
        own: arg,
        foo: function (){
                 alert("Foo");
             },
        bar: function (){
                 alert("Bar");
            }
    }

};

window.jQ = window.$ = jQ;

return jQ;
}());
```

I believe this style is actually preferred by Douglas Crockford because forgetting to use the new keyword won't throw an error but you'll get some very unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> JQuery allows us to use $ without the key word new. It has a function that returns a new instance automatically.

Nothing magical here. The `jQuery` function simply returns an instance of another constructor ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)):

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
},
```

The only magic going on in the code (not shown in the example) is that `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.prototype`. But [`jQuery.fn.init` is a different function than `jQuery`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/80022c81ce4a07a232afd3c580b0977555a2daec/src/core/init.js).

---

Applied to your example:

```
var jQ = function (arg){
    return new jQ.prototype.init(arg);
};

jQ.prototype = {

    init: function(arg) {
        this.own = arg;
    },

    // ...

};

jQ.prototype.init.prototype = jQ.prototype;
```

Comment: I've already seen that and I know the `.fn` is just the `.prototype`. So how can we have the same behavior with the exemple above ?

Comment: Try to call the method `foo` with your update using `$`... Or add a property which already has a value and display it using `$.property`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jb358df8/ ... and what should I do then? I don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scwzeh23/) ... take a look. I'm not perfect in english so maybe that I'm not explaining well

Comment: It's expected that `prop` is undefined. `prop` is a property of the object return ed by `$()`, not `$` itself. That's how jQuery works as well. Just try `$.on()`. It throws, because `.on` is a property of a jQuery object, not the jQuery function itself. I think you have a false idea of how jQuery works. `$` and `$()` are two different objects and they don't have shared properties. Every function you find on `$` was explicitly assigned to it.

Comment: I think that is what I was missing. They just add some methods in both `prototype` and `jQuery` object (directly).

Comment: Exactly! For example, this adds `get` and `post` to `jQuery` (`$`): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b091fdbafac33123cba329e6bb48b9281323ca38/src/ajax.js#L789

Comment: It was exactly what I was seeing. They do the same for the `ajax` method I think.