# Can you explain me how jQuery use $ as function and object the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I've looked into the jQuery sources and I don't exactly undestand how it can use $ symbol as function in selectors

```
$el = $('#element');
```

and as objects in helper-functions

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function(num) { ... });
```

$ function creates new jQuery.fn.init, which is somewhere in prototypes, I'm confused.

Comment: Functions **are** objects. Maybe this helps as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27496204/218196

Comment: Yes, I've made something like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function in Javascript is an object, so you can add properties to a function.

Example:

```
function lib(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

lib.add = function(a, b){
  return a + b;
};
```

Now you can use it both as a function and as an object having functions:

```
var n = lib(4); // n = 5

var m = lib.add(7, 8); // m = 15
```

jQuery does the same, just using `$` as a name instead of `lib` as I used in the example.

The `$` name is normally an alias for the `jQuery` name, and `jQuery.fn` is a reference to the prototype for the `jQuery` function. So when `jQuery.fn.init` is called, it's the same as `jQuery.prototype.init`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you write `lib` as an object literal?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: If you do that, then it's an object that isn't a function. A function is an object, but you can't make any object be a function.

Comment: Haha, ok, now I'm officially confused. Everything is an object, no? I figured that everything needs to start off as being `{ //keys and values }`...

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: What you get from an object literal is an object of the type `Object`. A function declaration creates an object of the type `Function`. You can't turn an object of type `Object` into an object of the type `Function`. An object of the type `Function` on the other hand inherits from the type `Object` so it has all its properties.

Comment: mind = blown. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

$ is just a shorthand for jquery, which represents a function.

In `$el = $('#element');`, $ (which is the same as jquery) is the function name that takes the selector as a function argument, resulting in the syntax `$();`

When executing this selector function, `jQuery.fn.init` (initializer function) is executed and returns the jQuery object, exposing the different selector methods that you can use.